# CakePHP won't fetch more than 800 rows

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to write a weekly report for a system. Part of the report will display information about translators that is not stored in the database - that is, for each translator I have to pull their DB record, run some logic, and for the ones that fail the logic I remove them from the array that gets passed to the view.

I would not anticipate having more than a couple dozen records left in the view, but there are just over 1,000 in the database. There is no way to limit the number getting pulled out of the database as the criteria I'm using is not stored there.

I'm using the following query to pull all rows. However, unless I add a 'limit' clause and limit it to 800 rows (I experimented with this), it won't actually return any results. If I debug the result array, it comes up blank. I have debugging mode on, but no errors are given at all, and there's nothing in the Cake logs or IIS logs either.

I have tried introducing an offset and limit and looping through in chunks but I have the same issue when I try to combine it all together again. After this find query, the memory usage is around 6MB, with the PHP limit set much higher (128MB I think).

Any ideas? I am stumped and pulling my hair out!

```
    $translators = $this->Translator->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array('Translator.translators_status_id' => 1),
                    array('Translator.translators_status_id' => 2)
                )
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Translator.id',
                'Translator.translators_status_id',
                'Translator.first_name',
                'Translator.last_name',
                'Translator.agency_name',
                'NativeLanguage.name',
                'Country.printable_name'
            ),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'languages',
                    'alias' => 'NativeLanguage',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Translator.language_id = NativeLanguage.id'
                    )
                ),              
                array(
                    'table' => 'countries',
                    'alias' => 'Country',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'NativeLanguage.country_id = Country.id'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

**EDIT:**
The solution I landed with was to only pull 500 rows at a time. Then on each batch of 500, I performed the logic test and removed rows from the array. Finally, I stitched each reduced batch back together.

Comment: I have come up with a solution. I worked through in chunks of 500 rows at a time, worked the logic and THEN stitched everything back together. Works like a charm. Would be interested to hear why the above isn't working though.

Comment: could it perhaps be a timeout?  How long does it normally take to finish running through 800 records?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a timeout; the results come up almost instantly (whether with 800 rows or with none).

Comment: Please post the query it's running when it returns no results (seems like this would be step #1 when debugging it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was nothing to do with memory after all. In CakePHP 2.2 (and possibly higher), the `debug()` function does not play nicely with certain UTF-8 characters if your database collation is not set to UTF-8. Running `debug()` on an array with any values containing these characters just ends up with "blank" output from the debugger. I assume that in my example above, I wasn't running into any problematic characters until the 800+nth row.

Now our DB collation is set to UTF-8 and CakePHP is set to connect to MySQL as UTF-8 and this problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just running out of memory.
There is (or was?) quite an interesting discussion about that here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/cake-php@googlegroups.com/msg50610.html